# ¿Cómo ejecutar un método desde otro método?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo 3 métodos declarados y quiero llamar el tercer metodo cuando se ejecute el primero o el segundo, con el fin de no tener que copiar y pegar todo el código que el método 3 contiene, me explico en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
 protected void btn_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {(... sus debidas instrucciones)}
 protected void btn_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {(... sus debidas instrucciones)}
 protected void btn_3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {(... sus debidas instrucciones)}
```

Lo que pretendo lograr pero me marca error es:

```
 protected void btn_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (... sus debidas instrucciones)
        btn_3_Click();
    }
 protected void btn_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (... sus debidas instrucciones)
        btn_3_Click();
    }
```

¿cómo se haría esto?

Comment: intentastes` btn_2_Click(sender , e)`

Comment: puedes enviar parámetros nulos `btn_3_Click(null, null);` en caso no usas los parámetros `sender` y `e`.

Comment: @JackNavaRow, casi casi es por ahí, ya no me marca error, pero me toca oprimir 2 veces el boton para que ejecute el otro método. Por ahí puede ser. gracias, seguiré probando.
Davilo, la verdad no se a que hace referencia esa cosa llamada sender , e, osea se que se pone siempre pero no se para que XD, siempre lo pongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por claridad de código deberías extraer la funcionalidad común a un método privado.

Algo así:

```
protected void btn_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (... sus debidas instrucciones)
    codigoComun();
}
protected void btn_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (... sus debidas instrucciones)
    codigoComun();
}
protected void btn_3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    codigoComun();
}
private void codigoComun()
{
    .... instrucciones comunes
}
```

Comment: Gracias por su respusta compa, acabo de probar eso, pero entonces el btnBoton3 en el .aspx me deja de funcionar dice algo asi: btnBoton3 _Click()' no es accesible debido a su nivel de protección, pero si creo que por ahi va la cosa

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta. No te comento que hagas privado el controlador del evento click del tercer botón, si no crear un nuevo método privado con la funcionalidad común y llamar desde los tres controladores de eventos a este nuevo método.

Comment: ahhh, ya veo por donde es la cosa, y en el botón 3 llamo el codigo común, si así es la cosa con esto, muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Lo más probable es que te falte la palabra reservada `this` para indicarle que se encuentra en la misma clase.

```
 protected void btn_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (... sus debidas instrucciones)
        this.btn_3_Click();
    }
 protected void btn_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (... sus debidas instrucciones)
        this.btn_3_Click();
    }
```

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta compa, pero no, lo agregué y sigue marcando error:  Nos e ha dado ningún argumento que corresponda (...)

Answer (score 0):

La llamada a metodos con evento en c# creo que es asi:
Btn_3.Click = new routedeventarg(btn_2_Click£:);

Ahora si al apretar cada boton quieres que se haga lo mismo :
Private void botones(object sender, eventarg e) 
{
Button botones = (sender)Button;
Botones.Click = new eventhandler(metodoaejecutar);
   }
Private void metodoaejecutar()
{
//CUALQUIER COSA
}

Y en el diseñador adjuntarle a cada boton el metodo botones

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta compadre, lo solucioné como me indicó Asier Villanueva, aun así está interesante tu propuesta, lo probaré en un próximo proyecto.